# Image Upload Using Spring MVC and Html

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, illegalargumentexception

I keep getting this error when i do with my spring mvc code i am trying to do image upload using spring mvc what is the arguments I am missing.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
...
```

My dispatcher  servlet is

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ImageUploadSpring.Controller" />

<!-- <bean id="simpleHandler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/> -->
     <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />  


    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

     <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
           <props>              
                <prop key="/Upload.html">FileUpload</prop>                  
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 
      <bean id="FileUpload" class="com.ImageUploadSpring.Controller.FileUpload">
        <property name="commandName" value="ImageUpload"/>  
         <property name="commandClass" value="com.ImageUploadSpring.Bean.UploadItem"/>
         <property name="formView" value="ImageUpload"/>
        <property name="successView" value="message"/> 
    </bean>
 <bean id="FileUpload" class="com.ImageUploadSpring.Controller.FileUpload"></bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>
```

**controller class is**

```
public class FileUpload extends SimpleFormController{

 @RequestMapping(value = "/Upload.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors,HttpSession session)  {
    System.out.println("inside submit method");
    try{

    UploadItem item=(UploadItem)command;



    MultipartFile file = item.getFile();

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    if (file.getSize() > 0) {
        inputStream = file.getInputStream();

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:/UploadedFiles/Images/"
                + file.getOriginalFilename());

        System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());

        int readBytes = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {

            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        session.setAttribute("uploadFile", "D:/UploadedFiles/Images/"
                + file.getOriginalFilename());
    }       


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    return new ModelAndView("message");

}
@Override
 protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder)
 throws ServletException {

     binder.registerCustomEditor(byte[].class, new ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor());

}
```

**And my html page is**

```
<form name="ImageUpload" action="/ImageUploadSpring/service/Upload.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
Select images:  
<input type="text" id="box"/> 
<input type="file" id="UploadFile" name="UploadFile"  onchange="CopyMe(this,'box');" accept="image/*" size="40" style="width: 91px;" multiple />
<br><br>  
<input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br><br>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While defining `<input type="file">` you have specified the name `name="UploadFile"`. Whereas in your UploadItem command object the file attribute is `file` (guessing from  item.getFile()). Are you sure you are correctly mapping the filename?

Please refer to [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multiple-file-upload-example/) for working tutorial on Spring MVC File Upload

Comment: i tried changing the name in the UplodItem Command Object ,but still the problem persists ,is there anything else i need to look to

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam(value="UploadFile") MultipartFile image, BindException errors,HttpSession session)
```

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-tutorial-single-and-multiple-files also works well for me. it is quite simple.
the important is when you use

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
</bean>
```

,
don't forget to add commons-fileupload to your pom dependencies.